# Model Derivative getModelViewProperties is limiting requests per minute. How can I have unlimited requests?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

The following api link for the Node JS package shows an endpoint that limits to 60 RPM: [forge-api docs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getModelviewProperties)

Support has said that 60RPM is only for endpoints where `forceget` is set to `true` in the options, and that the implicit value for the `forceget` option when calling `getModelviewProperties` is set to false, yet I'm still getting a limited to 60 requests per minute.

Even when setting `forceget` to `false` it limits the rpm.

How can I have more RPM for this endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these endpoints have to be limited for reasons. But I agree 60rpm with forceget=true is a very low limit. However, forceget=false has a 14000rpm limit. Note as well that forceget=true is ignored if the resources are still available in the cache from a previous call.

That means that you first call with forceget=false, and if there is a problem, you call the resource with forceget=true only once, and give it some time for the resources to be loaded in the cache. All following calls should be using forceget=false. That way, you would save your forceget=true quota.

If you still have problems, you can either let me know at cyrille at autodesk.com with an example, and I'll debug the problem with you.

Or an alternative is to parse/expand the db files yourself, which can be a very good option if you need to improve your application performance a lot. I got an old sample doing this [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/propertyServer) which is more powerful than the Forge API for querying properties. I am currently rewriting it in typescript in a new sample, but this one isn't ready yet - it will be posted [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/webhooks-properties).